# How to Conditionally Invoke a JavaScript Function from a Razor View Based on a Separate Controller Method?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a separate controller method which builds a HTML table and is created into my Razor view when invoked through an AJAX POST.

Please see the controller method snippet below:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("SupervisorWhereaboutsReport/{company}/{teamName}")]
        public DataResponse SupervisorWhereaboutsReport(string company, string teamName)
        {
           .......

            if (!result.Success)
            {
                return new DataResponse()
                {
                    Success = false,
                    ErrorMessage = result.ErrorMessage
                };
            }


            string hdr = "<table class='table table-sm table-hover table-bordered w-100'>" +
                            "<thead class='thead-dark sticky-top'\" style=\"top: 60px;\"><tr><th>Status</th><th>Job No</th><th>Photos/Notes</th><th>R No</th><th>WR No</th><th>Position</th><th>Address</th><th>Team</th><th>Req End Date</th><th>Area</th>" +
                                "<th>County</th><th>Dig Contractor</th><th>Road Type</th><th>Traffic Mgt</th></tr></thead>" +
                            "<tbody>";

            if (company != "AFF")
                hdr = "<table class='table table-sm table-hover table-bordered w-100'>" +
                            "<thead class='thead-dark'><tr><th>Status</th><th>Job No</th><th>Photos/Notes</th><th>R No</th><th>WR No</th><th>Position</th><th>Address</th><th>Team</th><th>Req End Date</th><th>Road Type</th><th>Traffic Mgt</th></tr></thead>" +
                            "<tbody>";


            foreach (DataRow item in result.Data.Rows)
            {
                if (district != item["district"].ToString())
                {
                    if (district != null)
                        rptOut += "</tbody></table></br>";

                    rptOut += hdr;

                    district = item["district"].ToString();
                }
                if (company == "AFF")
                    rptOut += "<tr>"
                            + "<td>" + item["tpe"].ToString() + "</td>"
                            + "<td><a href='/Job?JobNo=" + ((int)item["JobNo"]).ToString() + "' target='_blank'>" + ((int)item["JobNo"]).ToString() + "</a></td>"
                            + "<td><i class=\"fas fa-comments\" onclick=\"ShowJobNotes()\" style=\"cursor:pointer\"></i></td>"
                            + "<td>" + item["RNo"].ToString() + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item["ClientJobNum"].ToString() + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item["position"].ToString() + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item["Addr"].ToString().Replace(", ,", ", ") + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item["Team"].ToString() + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + ((DateTime)item["ReqComplDate"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item["district"].ToString() + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item["area"].ToString() + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item["Dig_Contractor"].ToString() + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item["RoadType"].ToString() + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item["TrafficMgtRef"].ToString() + "</td>"
                        + "</tr>";
                else

           .......
        }
```

Where the line of code I am focused on is:

```
+ "<td><i class=\"fas fa-comments\" onclick=\"ShowJobNotes()\" style=\"cursor:pointer\"></i></td>"
```

My question is, how do I invoke the ShowJobNotes() JavaScript function found in my Razor view from my controller method?:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        function runReport() {
            var selectedTeam = $("#Team").val();
            var selectedCompany = $("#Companies").val();
              
        $("#isBusy").show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ReportsAPI/SupervisorWhereaboutsReport/" + selectedCompany + "/" + selectedTeam,
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data, status, xhttp) {
                    if (!data.success) {
                        alert(data.ErrorMessage);
                        return;
                    }    //$("#rno_error").show();
                    //result
                    $("#divRpt").html(data.result);
                    console.log(data.result);

                $("#isBusy").hide();

                },
                failure: function (errMsg) {
                    console.log("FAILED!");
                    alert(errMsg);
                }
            });

        function ShowJobNotes(){
            window.open("/Job/Notes?jobno=" + $(".JobNumber").val()+"&fullname="+$("#FullName").val(), $(".JobNumber").val()+" Notes", "width=900,height=1000");
            return false;
        }
}
    </Script>
}
```

I'm not sure how to get this to work as the controller method isn't actually part of my page model. It's a separate file which stores a bunch of endpoints used across various related classes. Trying to invoke the function on my webpage results in ShowJobNotes() is not defined error.

Comment: Given the position of the last `}` your `function ShowJobNotes()` is *inside* `function runReport()` - move it outside so that it's globally available to your `onclick=` HTML attribute.  Alternatively, use javascript events instead of `onclick=` (you'd need event delegation)

Comment: @freedomn-m This is what the issue was! I can't believe I didn't see that lol. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your @section Scripts{ .. }, add the following

```
$(document).on('load','.fas.fa-comments',function(e){
  ShowJobNotes();
 //or.. 
 $('.fas.fa-comments').trigger('click');
});
```